# Error when trying to create balanced train set with SMOTE

Tags: r, classification, training-data

I am trying to create new data to receive a balanced train set for classification with decision tree. When using the **SMOTE** function, I am always getting the same error:

> Error in names(dn) <- dnn : attempt to set an attribute on NULL 
>   In addition: Warning message: In names(data) == as.character(form[[2]]) :
>   longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

I converted everything to factor with `as.factor()` and deleted the NA's:

```
train <- na.omit(train)



> str(train)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   11526 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ number: Factor w/ 2 levels "problem",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Land: Factor w/ 29 levels "Australien","Belgien",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 9 3 ...
 $ direction: Factor w/ 2 levels "LL","RL": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 ...
 $ transmission: Factor w/ 2 levels "AUT","SCH": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ range: Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 3 3 3 2 1 3 2 4 3 2 ...
 - attr(*, "na.action")= 'omit' Named int  6500 9748
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "6500" "9748"
```

The head of my train set looks like this:

```
> head(train,10)
     number          Land           direction  transmission       range 
1  reference Bundesrep. Deutschland      LL         AUT             3
2  reference Bundesrep. Deutschland      LL         AUT             3
3  reference Bundesrep. Deutschland      LL         AUT             3
4  reference Bundesrep. Deutschland      LL         AUT             2
5  reference Bundesrep. Deutschland      LL         AUT             1
6  reference Bundesrep. Deutschland      LL         AUT             3
7  reference Bundesrep. Deutschland      LL         AUT             2
8  problem                   Taiwan      LL         AUT             3
9  reference Bundesrep. Deutschland      LL         AUT             4
10 reference        Grossbritannien      RL         AUT             3
11 reference Bundesrep. Deutschland      LL         SCH             2
```

And this is my code:

```
library(DMWr)
smote_train <- SMOTE(train$number ~ ., data  = train, perc.over=500, k =5)
```

Comment: it's `library(DMwR)` not `DMWr`, but probably it's just a typo in your question. Also you can write just `number` in the formula, not `train$number`.